# Generate python soaplib code based on WSDL and XSD files

Tags: python, soap, xsd, wsdl, soaplib

I've WSDL, and XSD files and want to generate a soaplib python stubs code based on WSDL, XSD files is there a tool or a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

check this link and resolution code python for soaplib useful content

[Using soaplib as django views](https://gist.github.com/Apkawa/1106206)

[Python web services with SoapLib](http://www.carlosble.com/2008/05/python-web-services-with-soaplib/)

[Webservice + WSDL](http://webpy.org/cookbook/webservice)